# Access favicon.ico is too slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I using the ROR to develop a website

http://obscure-dawn-8643.herokuapp.com

When I first time access my website

The website always wait a long time then response to me

This is too slow!!!

I Observed the log, it's seem this action cost the mostly time

```
2015-08-09T14:47:04.305046+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-dawn-8643.herokuapp.com request_id=6b051df7-dc41-4e43-8192-9a517421b06b fwd="123.110.225.207" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=228
```

Does this action is necessary?

How can I remove this action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed your app is hosted on Heroku. This is an excerpt from their [documentation on this particular topic](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/6/20/app_sleeping_on_heroku).

> When an app on Heroku has only one web dyno and that dyno doesn't
>   receive any traffic in 1 hour, the dyno goes to sleep.
>
> When someone accesses the app, the dyno manager will automatically
>   wake up the web dyno to run the web process type. This causes a short
>   delay for this first request, but subsequent requests will perform
>   normally.
>
> Apps that have more than 1 web dyno running never go to sleep and
>   worker dynos (or other process types) are never put to sleep.

I hope this answers your question. Please see the documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

I will reference this document for more information.